# Are there any frum comic books?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, books-generally, chinuch-education

I am looking for comic books or graphic novels which depict orthodox Judaism, and teach torah lessons. I am aware of Rabbi Wein's books which are more historical, I'm looking for something that is more super-hero-esque, something that is geared to appeal to an American 10 year old. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Mendy and the Golem?

Comment: Not on Gershon's list but enjoyable (teen Orthodox girl hero): [Hereville: How Mirka Got Her Sword](http://www.amazon.com/Hereville-How-Mirka-Got-Sword/dp/1419706195).  (There's also a sequel.)

Comment: There's an old one called [Shaloman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaloman), who is basically a Jewish Superman. I don't remember precisely how _frum_ it is, but it's definitely based around Jewish storylines. There are some online places that still sell it ([e.g.](http://www.jewishstore.com/Books/Shaloman.asp))

Answer (score 9):

Yes. [Here is a page from Eichlers full of Jewish comic books](http://www.eichlers.com/children-s-section/children-s-books/comic-books.html)

Comment: That "Escape from Seville" seems like it would be right up your 10 year-old's alley and I wanted to buy it for my son, but be warned: based on a comment [here](http://www.feldheim.com/escape-from-seville.html) you would also need part two and another 20 bucks to complete the story.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://www.naviillustrated.com/) for a relatively new series that depicts the stories in Nach replete with *midrashic* explanations and insights. Great art, with actual *pesukim* and their accompanying translation to keep the narrative flow. I have the first book they put out (full disclosure: I got it for myself; my kids were an afterthought) and was very taken by it.

Answer (score 1):

There a few that I know of.

[Rashi HaKadosh: A Light After the Dark Ages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583309527)

[Rambam: The Story of Maimonides](http://www.nehora.com/rambam-the-story-of-maimonides/)

[Shmuel HaNagid: A Tale of the Golden Age - Book 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583307346) (Book 2 is out there I just can't find a link right now.)

Rashi and Rambam are by Rabbi Berel Wein; Shmuel HaNagid is by Aryeh Mahr. They are great books and are good for introducing the biographies of these sages.